# Real symmetric 3x3 eigenvectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In some 'fiddling about' with 3x3 real symmetric matrices, related to wave propagation, I noticed that:
       Real symmetric matrix **S** with eigenvalue L (one of the three).

```
   **T**= **S** - L.

   **D** is matrix of co-factors of **T**.

  The matrix **D***= **D**/ trace(**D**) is the outer product of the eigenvector **n** associated with the value L. i.e. D*ij = ni nj
```

So, the eigenvector component values can be found from the square roots of the diagonal components of **D***, and the signs ( + and - of each eigenvector are equally valid of course) from the other components. 
The trace of **D** must not be zero, of course. 
Computationally this is probably of no value compared with using 'standard' methods but I wondered how well known this was- and is there a simple reason? Please bear in mind that I'm an Engineer and a manifold to me is something that bolts onto a cylinder head...

Comment: Sorry, missed the identity matrix, I, out of the definition of T.  T= S - I L i.e T is the matrix S minus the eigenvalue for each leading diagonal element.

Comment: the matrix of co-factors is the transpose of the adjoint, so its rows and coloumns are eigenvectors for T and for S

Answer (score 1):

- $D$ is the matrix of co-factors of a symmetric matrix, so it's itself a symmetric matrix, and it's also the adjoint
- By definition of adjoint, $DT=TD=0$, so the rows and coloumns of $D$ are eigenvectors for the eigenvalue $L$ of $S$
- If $L$ was a simple eigenvector of $S$, and $v=[a,b,c]^T$ is an eigenvector, then $D$ can only have the form of
  $$D=c v v^T$$
  with $c$ a constant different from zero.
- The trace of $D$ is now $c(a^2+b^2+c^2)=c|v|^2$, so
  $$D^*=ww^T \qquad w=v/|v|$$
- If $L$ isn't a simple eigenvalues, then $D=0$

Conclusion: your method works only for simple eigenvalues

Comment: Thanks Exodd, I think I'm happy with that. I realised the matrix of co-factors was a scalar multiple of the inverse (symmetric matrix), and guess you meant DT=TD=I. I shall work it through properly when I get time.

Comment: WHOOPS!  Yes, DT=TD=0 not I.

Comment: Or does it? I'm just getting confused... especially as <return> finishes the comment on this site. For the eigenvector thing to work, yes, DT=0 but is that a property of the adjoint? I thought it was just a scalar multiple of the inverse so that would not be true?

Comment: when the matrx is invertible, then it is a multiple of the inverse. But T, in this case, is singular. In general, if $A$ is a matrix, and $B$ her adjoint, then

$$AB=BA=det(A)I$$
If $A$ is singular, then $det(A)=0$

Comment: Yes, of course; T is singular by definition!  Thank you very much, Exodd,  for both answering the question and putting up with the "brain scramble".  @Exodd

Comment: I'll add a comment that checking the singularity of T (in my usage) when the components of the original matrix are numerically large will magnify any errors in the calculation of the eigenvalues to a very large extent, because of cubic terms in the determinant.